# Print Axis2 Request Response XML

Tags: java, apache-axis

I want to print RAW Request Response XML to console. I have created the stubs using wsdl2java axis2.

wsdl2java has created 2 java files, one for stub and one for callbackhandler.

I am trying with below method but getting null value for

```
operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");
/
operationContext.getMessageContext("In");.
```

Code

```
public void SOAPLogHandler(Stub stub){  

ServiceContext serviceConxt = stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext();

//**** Enable the Cache to hold the last operation
OperationContext OperationContext  = new OperationContext();
boolean cacheLastOperationContext = true;
OperationContext.setComplete(true); // Enable the Cache value
serviceConxt.setCachingOperationContext(cacheLastOperationContext);
serviceConxt.setLastOperationContext(OperationContext);

OperationContext operationContext = serviceConxt.getLastOperationContext();

if (operationContext != null) {
         MessageContext outMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");
             operationContext.getMessageContexts();
        if (outMessageContext != null) {
            System.out.println("OUT SOAP: "+outMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
             }
     MessageContext inMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("In");
if (inMessageContext != null) {
    System.out.println("IN SOAP: "+ inMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
                  }
           }
```

Can you please let me know is there any other way to get the raw xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately unless you intercept the message via say tcp monitor, you will have a tough time getting the raw message.

Comment: Not a useful comment.

Answer (score 13):

I managed to do so by adding a couple of lines in a method of the stub (the one you call to invoke the web service).
I identified the line, i.e.

```
_operationClient.execute(true);
```

that effectively contacts the web service and added just after it:

```
_operationClient.getMessageContext("Out").getEnvelope().serialize(System.out);
_operationClient.getMessageContext("In").getEnvelope().serialize(System.out);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  I was able to print every response from the WS by which I was retrieving the SOAP envelopes.

Comment: For me, that printed out nearly the complete outgoing message except for the WS-Security header added by rampart.

Comment: this working for me too,But everytime i do build the  line of code i add in the stub which is a generated code gets removed. Any  idea to implement this outside of the generated code?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code:

```
  OperationContext OperationContext  = new OperationContext();
  boolean cacheLastOperationContext = true;
  OperationContext.setComplete(true); // Enable the Cache value
  serviceConxt.setCachingOperationContext(cacheLastOperationContext);
  serviceConxt.setLastOperationContext(OperationContext);
```

You are explicitly creating **new operationContext** and and setting it to **LastOperationContext**. That is why you are getting null.

I used same code, just removed part which is **setting  setLastOperationContext**.

It is working for me atleast for Out Message.

for In I am getting exception stating that "Attempted read on closed stream".

Answer (score 0):

Starting with kekolab solution above, I wrote a method that can be used to log the outgoing and ingoing xmls :

After each  `_operation.execute(true)`, call `logPayload` :

```java
_operationClient.execute(true);
logPayload(_operationClient);
```

which is defined as :

```java
  private void logPayload(OperationClient operationClient) {
    try {
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      operationClient.getMessageContext("Out").getEnvelope().serialize(out);
      logger.info(out.toString() + "\n\n");
      operationClient.getMessageContext("In").getEnvelope().serialize(out);
      logger.info(out.toString() + "\n\n");
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Worked really nice for me and included the security tags inserted inside the soap enveloppe header as well.